# Why is this spec failing, when the conditions it's testing pass in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, omniauth

I have a `User` model and `Authentications` model, which is a basic omniauth setup. Essentially, users can sign up through oauth without setting a password.

I have a `Authentication.is_destroyable?` method that returns true if the user has a password or has more than one authentication. Essentially, this prevents users deleting their one and only way of authentication.

```
def is_destroyable?
  if user.encrypted_password.present? || user.authentications.count > 1
    true
  else
    errors.add :base, 'not allowed'
    false
  end
end
```

When testing this in development it works as expected under all conditions. However, my unit tests are failing:

```
describe "Authentication#is_destroyable?" do

  before(:each) do
    # This creates a user with no password and a single authentication
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_oauth)
    @auth = @user.authentications.first
  end

  # This spec passes :)
  it "should return false when is users only authentication method" do
    @auth.is_destroyable?.should be_false
  end

  # This FAILS - I have no idea why :(
  it "should return true when user has multiple authentications" do
    @user.authentications.create FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:authentication, :provider => 'twitter')
    @auth.is_destroyable?.should be_true
  end

  # This FAILS - I have no idea why :(
  it "should return true when user has a password" do
    @user.update_attributes :password => 'password'
    @auth.is_destroyable?.should be_true
  end

end
```

I've spent the best part of 3 hours banging my head against the wall. I can't for the life of me understand why this works when I manually test the functionality (and Cucumber stories pass also testing the functionality), but in rspec the unit tests are failing. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

#### Edit

As requested, here's some further detail.

Both failing specs fail with:

```
Failure/Error: @auth.is_destroyable?.should be_true
  expected false to be true
```

The Factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    username  { FactoryGirl.generate(:username) }
    name      'Test User'
    email     { FactoryGirl.generate(:email) }
    password  'password'
  end

  factory :user_with_oauth, :parent => :user do
    password        nil
    authentications [ FactoryGirl.build(:authentication) ]
  end

  factory :authentication do
    provider  'facebook'
    uid       SecureRandom.hex(16)
  end

end
```

Also, maybe relevant, am using DatabaseCleaner with the *truncation* strategy.

Comment: what's the factory for the auth?

Comment: can you show the failure output?

Comment: Have edited the original post

Comment: Have added all the relevant factories now.

Comment: Just for a check, does using `@user.authentications.create!` (note the use of `!`) throw an exception? And in the line after that, try reloading `@auth` instead of depending on the one assigned in the `before(:each)`? And also check if the second auth record did actually get created in the database.

Comment: @zabba, using `create!` raises no exceptions so that must be OK. Following that I've reloaded `@auth` with `@auth = Authentication.last`. Still fails.

Comment: @Zabba OK this is interesting - in that same test after the `create!` method I've added two further assertions: `@user.authentications.should have(2).auths` which passes; `Authentication.all.should have(2).auths` which fails, saying only 1 auth exists. Seems like the authentication is not getting save in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer my own question (after 2 more hours of hitting my head against the wall)...

My `:user_with_oath` Factory was to blame; I wasn't wrapping the authentications association in a block:

```
factory :user_with_oauth, :parent => :user do
  password        nil
  authentications { [FactoryGirl.build(:authentication)] }
end
```